# How to align inline-block elements inside flex box?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an outer `div` which is a flex box. Inside it, there will be three elements as inline-block: two advertisements on the left and right, and the content in between. I want the advertisements to be aligned to the left and right and then work on my content in the middle as if the ads were the margins of the page (I hope this is clear). I'm having to use a lot of `&nbsp;` spaces but is there a way to directly place the two ads on either sides of the flex box?  I tried using `position:right` and `float:right;` properties but these didn't work.

Here's my code:

```
<!---==OUTER DIV==-->
<div id="content-flex" style="display:flex;">


    <!--====LEFT SIDE AD====-->

    <div style="display:inline-block; position:left;">
        <span style="color:white;">Advertisement</span><br/>
        <a href="http://www.bmw.com.au" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/zuTk53kSNOJJC/giphy.gif" />
        </a><br/>
    </div>

    <!--HERE I HAVE TO USE A LOT OF &nbsp;-->



    <!--====MIDDLE : CONTEN====T-->

    <div style="display:inline-block;">

        <p>Loreum Ipsum...</p>

    </div>

    <!--HERE I HAVE TO USE A LOT OF &nbsp;-->



    <!--====RIGHT SIDE AD====-->

    <div style="display:inline-block; position:right;">
        <span style="color:white;">Advertisement</span><br/>
        <a href="http://www.bmw.com.au" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/zuTk53kSNOJJC/giphy.gif" />
        </a>

    </div>

</div>
```

This is how the page looks right now:

[image]

Comment: Do these elements need to be inline-block? Can't you just use the flex model to get the desired result?

Comment: @Obsidian If I don't make them `inline-block`, won't they go on separate lines? I want them on the same line.

Comment: `position: right` is invalid and floating flex children has no effect. You should [read up on how to use flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: No flex box can be in rows or columns. Rows are the default so do not need referencing. See my answer below on an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just set `flex: 1` on middle div it will take all the free space and push right ad to right side. Also once you set `display: flex` on parent element `float` property won't work on child elements.

```css
#content-flex > div:nth-child(2) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-flex" style="display:flex;">

  <div>
    <span style="color:white;">Advertisement</span>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://www.bmw.com.au" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/zuTk53kSNOJJC/giphy.gif" />
    </a>
    <br/>
  </div>

  <div>
    <p>Loreum Ipsum...</p>
  </div>

  <div >
    <span style="color:white;">Advertisement</span>
    <br/>
    <a href="http://www.bmw.com.au" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/zuTk53kSNOJJC/giphy.gif" />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: And I can just add some padding to the middle div to space it away from the ads. This worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following style to your outer `div`.

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

or

```
justify-content: space-around;
```

[Look here for more alignment options for `flex`](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp).

Comment: Just one doubt: the middle div gets center aligned in the space between. How to make it justified?

Comment: what do you mean by "justified"? what is the desired placement of the middle div?

Answer (score 1):

This is how it can be managed using the flex box model:

```css
#content-flex,
#AdLft,
#AdRgt{
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.Middle{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-flex">

  <div id="AdLft">
    <a href="http://www.bmw.com.au" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/zuTk53kSNOJJC/giphy.gif" />
    </a>
  </div>

  <div class="Middle">
    <p>Loreum Ipsum...</p>
  </div>

  <div id="AdRgt">
    <a href="http://www.bmw.com.au" target="_blank">
      <img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/zuTk53kSNOJJC/giphy.gif" />
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```